# StringLength validation always returns true

Tags: c#, validation, .net-6.0

I'm trying to use the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations classes to simplify data model validation, and I hit a roadblock. The `Required` attributes are working as expected for my class, but when I try `MaxLength` or `StringLength`, `Validator.TryValidateObject()` returns successfully. I'm stumped, after trying everything I can possibly think of.

## Model Class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class MyClass
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    //[MaxLength(3)] <===== This also yields the same result
    public string? MyField { get; set; }
}
```

## Test Class

*Uses xunit and FluentAssertions*

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using FluentAssertions;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

public class MyClassTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void MyFieldCantExceed50Characters()
    {
        var obj = new MyClass
        {
            MyField = "12345",
        };

        ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var validated = Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, new ValidationContext(obj), validationResults);
        validated.Should().BeFalse(); // <===== This assertion fails
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `validateAllProperties` parameter to `true`.
According to Microsoft:

> `true` to validate all properties; if `false`, only required attributes are validated.

Your should call the method like so:

```cs
var validated = Validator.TryValidateObject(x, new ValidationContext(x), validationResults, true);
```

Another option is to use `ValidateObject` that will throw an exception if any requirement is not met.

Sources:

- [`ValidateObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.validateobject?view=net-6.0)
- [`TryValidateObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.tryvalidateobject?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Thanks, that argument is helpful as a workaround (it gets me the desired behavior), but my real property actually has the `[Required]` attribute, so it seems like the documentation is inconsistent. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Dov it depends on how you  interpret that "only Required attributes". You seem to expect "all attributes of properties that are marked Required" while the implementation seems to be "*just* the Required attributes,  ignoring any others"